# How to get MySql DB connection information from MySql workbench?

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, workbench

I am trying to connect to a database using ASP.net and C#. I went through the MySql workbench tutorial and created a database, eer model, and table.

What I need now is the database connection information, specifically the connection string. How do I find what information needs to go in the connection string? What all needs to be in my connection string?

Comment: A solution has been posted by the community.here is the link :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697251/issue-with-connection-string-in-web-config-file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Issue with connection string in web config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697251/issue-with-connection-string-in-web-config-file)

Answer (score 5):

[ConnectionStrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com) is an excellent resource for details on connection strings and how they can be constructed.